# Rewrite query with COUNT(*) and GROUP BY as Cartesian Join

Tags: sql, oracle, peoplesoft

I would like to ask whether it is possible to rewrite the following query:

```
SELECT TEAM, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT    ID, TEAM
    FROM      MY_TABLE
    WHERE     TO_CHAR(A.SUBMIT_DATE, 'YYYY') = '2019' 
    GROUP BY  ID, TEAM
)
GROUP BY TEAM
```

using the cartesian join style?
The reason is that I'm using Peoplesoft and it does not allow such subquery without creating another view for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner query is flattening out the table to get distinct `ID` and `TEAM` combinations for 2019, which are then counted by the outer query. You can shortcut it to a simple `COUNT(DISTINCT)` query:

```
SELECT TEAM, COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(SUBMIT_DATE, 'YYYY') = '2019'
GROUP BY TEAM;
```

**NOTEs:**

- As Gary Myers points out in the comments, this won't work if there are null `ID` values. If `ID` is nullable, see the next bullet point.
- Brilliant hack from Tejash in the notes below, to use if `ID` can be NULL:

  ```
  SELECT TEAM, COUNT(DISTINCT ID || TEAM)
  ... and then the rest of the query from above
  ```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8eef4/4) with your query and mine. Tejash [also did a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54c487e37020cc42a79d6b7df823694f).

One more thing. If you have a lot of records (thousands or more), and if you have an index on `SUBMIT_DATE`, you can optimize the query by *not* using a function on `SUBMIT_DATE`:

```
SELECT TEAM, COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE SUBMIT_DATE >= DATE '2019-01-01'
  AND SUBMIT_DATE <  DATE '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY TEAM;
```

If it's a big table with lots of rows and lots of years, the optimized version will be noticeably faster.

Comment: Very minor nitpick, but if ID has null values, there will be a slight discrepancy between the count(*), which will count the nulls. and count(distinct id), which won't.

Comment: Good catch @GaryMyers, thanks! Null handling counts; it's not minor. If the OP runs into trouble with nulls I'll have a bash at updating. Best I can think of now is a `COALESCE` / `NVL` hack.

Comment: You can handle it with concatenation `COUNT(DISTINCT ID||TEAM)` -- see [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54c487e37020cc42a79d6b7df823694f)

Comment: Brilliant @Tejash----ORA-00980! I thought at the time "I know there's a quick and easy way" but I couldn't come up with it. This is it.